# Convert answer to percentage with two decimals place SQL

Tags: percentage

I’m trying to figure out how to convert the Male Percentage column to a percentage with decimals to the hundredths

```
select Top 20 pa.State,
Sum(case when p.gender='M' then 1 else 0  end) as [Male Count],
Sum(case when p.gender='F' then 1 else 0 end) as [ Female Count],
100*sum(case when gender='m' then 1 else 0 end )/count(*) as [Male Percentage]

From [dbo].[Patients] as p
Join PatientAddresses as pa
on p.mrn=pa.MRN
group by pa.State
```

The results I got.

| State | Male Count | Female Count | Male Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UT | 105 | 120 | 46 |
| NC | 1152 | 1123 | 50 |
| WI | 700 | 669 | 51 |
| MA | 1486 | 1424 | 51 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server by default will report integer division as integer numbers.  If you want to force two decimal places, use `ROUND(x, 2)`, where `x` is a float.  One way to make `x` a float here is to multiply the percentage by the float `100.0` instead of the integer `100`.

```
SELECT TOP 20
    pa.State,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'M' THEN 1 END) AS [Male Count],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'F' THEN 1 END) AS [Female Count],
    ROUND(100.0*COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*), 2) AS [Male Percentage]
FROM [dbo].[Patients] AS p
INNER JOIN PatientAddresses AS pa
    ON p.mrn = pa.MRN
GROUP BY
    pa.State;
```

Side note: Using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` does not make much sense, because it is not clear *which* 20 records you want to see.  So, adding an `ORDER BY` clause here is probably what you want, unless you are OK with getting back 20 random states.

**Edit:**

If you want to *view* the output in SSMS with only two decimal places, and not just with a precision of 2 decimal places, then use `CONVERT`:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 100.0*COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*))
```

Comment: Thank you i did that and not its giving me more than two decimals. I assume i can change that with modifying the count(*), 2)?

Comment: Not sure what you want here, I have given you two decimals in the percentage, as you asked.

Comment: Sorry im super grateful for your help, the first result came back as such 46.670000000000 . im trying to format as 46.67%

Comment: @LamarReynolds This requirement is typically handled in your presentation layer, i.e. whatever is calling SQL Server.  If you _must_ handle it from SSMS, then use `CONVERT` to a decimal, q.v. the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and the explanation, it make sense know.

Comment: yeah, i just trying to figure how how to add the sign of % but it does answer my question. thank you